# Boot into Windows 7 from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows

How to boot into Windows 7 (or other OS) without having to select it from the GRUB menu? Note that I am not trying to switch the order in the menu, I'm looking for a way in Ubuntu to temorarily do something like "Restart and boot into X". Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you looked at creating a virtual machine using either [VMWare](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0), or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: I use VirtualBox in a different context, but I'm talking about dual-boot (as you're aware, resources are also taken by the host, so I'm interested in a real boot into windows).

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, and it sounds like some manual editing is required but GrubReboot allows you to specify which operating system to reboot into using a simple command. A number is assigned to each OS entry in grub, to reboot into an OS just open your terminal and type:

```
grub-reboot #
```

Most of the information I found was for Debian, but it sounds like this program may be pre-installed on Ubuntu? Anyways it might be worth a look.

Information I Found On It:

https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Comment: Excellent! I got it to work. Note that you might include having to update the grub file and run grub-update. Afterwards it will be possible to run 'sudo grub-reboot [num]'. Also note that it is zero indexed (entry 5 is num=4). Next, 'sudo reboot' will actually just highlight the number (and not directly boot into it). You might want to lower the time out, then again I imagined a too short time and then being stuck in case something happens to ubuntu. Thank you!